# python nested classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, here's my test code, I'm using python 3.2.x:

```
class account:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    class bank:
        def __init__(self):
            self.balance = 100000

        def balance(self):
            self.balance

        def whitdraw(self, amount):
            self.balance -= amount

        def deposit(self, amount):
            self.balance += amount
```

when I do:

```
a = account()
a.bank.balance
```

I expected to get the value of balance returned, instead I get the function "balance", why is this? It returns the value of balance when I do:

```
class bank:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 100000

    def balance(self):
        self.balance

    def whitdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

a = bank()
a.balance
```

So I want to know why this is and it would be great if someone could come up with a way to give me the value of balance in the nested version.

Comment: May be a.bank.balance() (note: trailing brackets) will return correct value?

Comment: TypeError: ret_balance() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Don't you need an instance of bank? i.e., in the `__init__` method of `account`, you need something like `self.my_bank = bank()`, I think. Then check with `a = account()` and `balance = a.my_bank.balance` should be 100000.

Comment: You need to read a Python tutorial. See for instance http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @codeape, that's what I was reading before posting here...

Comment: @bendundee, that is impossible: NameError: global name 'bank' is not defined

Comment: @BenDundee -- It needs to be `self.my_bank = self.__class__.bank()` or similar.  the namespace that is created with the class gets attached to the class when it is finalized -- so the methods don't actually get to pull information from that scope.  See my answer.

Comment: There's almost never any need to nest class *definitions*. Certainly, there is no need to do it here.

Comment: Read it again, but slower this time :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My version of your code, with comments:

```
#
# 1. CamelCasing for classes
#
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        # 2. to refer to the inner class, you must use self.Bank
        # 3. no need to use an inner class here
        self.bank = self.Bank()

    class Bank:
        def __init__(self):
            self.balance = 100000

        # 4. in your original code, you had a method with the same name as 
        #    the attribute you set in the constructor. That meant that the 
        #    method was replaced with a value every time the constructor was 
        #    called. No need for a method to do a simple attribute lookup. This
        #    is Python, not Java.

        def withdraw(self, amount):
            self.balance -= amount

        def deposit(self, amount):
            self.balance += amount

a = Account()
print(a.bank.balance)
```

Answer (score 10):

There are several problems:

1. You're using the name `balance` for both the data member and for the function.
2. You're missing a `return` statement in `balance()`.
3. `balance()` operates on an *instance* of `bank`. There is no instance in `a.bank.balance`: here, `a.bank` refers to the inner class itself.

Comment: changed the balance function's name to ret_balance and added return in it's body, same result though

Comment: reading the other comments I'm convinced you're explanation of WHY it doesn't work is correct, do you have an idea on a way it would work?

Comment: @Daquicker: You need to create an *instance* of `bank` within the instance of `account` (just make sure the class and the instance don't have the same name).

Comment: Tried that by adding my_bank = bank() to the end of the account class, kinda doesn't work either, gives me this: <bound method bank.ret_balance of <__main__.bank object at 0x02D68E70>>

Comment: allright, found a way, just needed to add the brackets at the end, bumped into another problem though, when I have a = account() and change the value of balance by a.mybank.whitdraw(50000) and then do b = account(), the result of b.mybank.ret_balance also is 50000... while I want it to be 100000

Answer (score 1):

`a.bank` is the **class** (not instance) since you've never created an *instance* of the bank on `a`.  So if `a.bank` is a class, `a.bank.balance` is a method bound to that class.

This works however:

```
class account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bank = account.bank()

    class bank:
        def __init__(self):
            self.balance = 100000

        def whitdraw(self, amount):
            self.balance -= amount

        def deposit(self, amount):
            self.balance += amount

a = account()
print a.bank.balance
```

Of course, as you show working code without nested classes, It really begs the question about *why* you want to use nested classes for this.  I would argue that the non-nested version is much cleaner.

Comment: @Daquicker -- classes are really neat, and nesting them isn't really a problem once you understand python's scoping rules (which is definitely worth investing some time to learn).  The main thing that I was trying to point out is that from a program design, it doesn't really make much sense in this case -- Actually, I tend to believe it doesn't make much sense in *most* cases, but maybe that's just because I haven't met those cases yet ;-).  Anyway, this is still useful stuff to work through as an exercise.

Comment: I wanted to nest them because I need more things in account than only a bank and building classes for each major part seemed to be the neatest way to do it... I just want to keep everyhing together so it doesn't get scattered all across the code...