# Creating multi-layered Python classes with access to variables within each layer

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

In Python 2.7, I'm trying to create classes within classes (and so on), like for example:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, device_name):
        self.device_name = device_name

    class Profile(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

    class Measurement(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2
```

Using this layering to create objects, I need to be able to assign and access any variable in any layer, like for example:

```
test1 = Test("Device_1")
Test.Profile(test1, 10, 20)
Test.Measurement(test1, 5, 6)

print test1.Profile.x1
print test1.Measurement.x1
```

It should also be noted that I need to load the classes with data taken from a text file.

I thought that using classes would be the best way of achieving this but I'd be happy to hear any other ideas.

Comment: why you create classes within classes?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You can put Profile and Measurement classes to separate file and return just instances of these classes from Test class. You don't need to do that nesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python nested classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606559/python-nested-classes)

Answer (score 0):

My version/solution [class scopes](http://igotgenes.blogspot.de/2009/01/class-attributes-and-scoping-in-python.html):

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, device_name):
        self.device_name = device_name

    class Profile(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

    class Measurement(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

test1 = Test("Device_1")
prof = test1.Profile(10, 20)
meas= test1.Measurement(5, 6)

print (prof.x1)
print (meas.x1) 

>>> 10
>>> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know why you want nested classes, this will do exactly as you want. If you look at the example, be sure to note the change in syntax.

```
class Test(object):
    class Profile(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

    class Measurement(object):
        def __init__(self, x1, x2):
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

    def __init__(self, device_name):
        self.device_name = device_name
        self.profile = None
        self.measurement = None

    def make_profile(self, a, b):
        self.profile = self.Profile(a, b)

    def make_measurement(self, a, b):
        self.measurement = self.Measurement(a, b)

test1 = Test("Device_1")
test1.make_profile(10, 20)
test1.make_measurement(5, 6)

print (test1.profile.x1)
print (test1.measurement.x1)
```

Output:

```
10
5
```

Comment: are the extra methods really needed?

Comment: In your solution, you create separate objects, whereas mine has them all in the same object. You could theoretically pass in all the arguments in the original constructor, but it didn't seem like that's what he wanted.

Comment: in your case, you can't access the profile and measurement for test1 from test1 because you are creating them separately. I don't agree with the whole nesting classes thing, but the OP seemed to want to be able to access profile and measurement from within the Test object, which i have provided functionality for.

Comment: That's what I was aiming for. Would it be possible to add another class within 'Profile' or 'Measurement'?

Comment: Yes, but there are better ways to go about doing what it seems you want

Comment: What ways would you suggest instead?

Comment: I would make each class top level, and then make nested objects. It would also help to know a little more about what you want your data structure to do.